# Summernote: "Codeview" doesn't properly render entries from the database (Meteor/MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, wysiwyg, summernote

I'm using the summernote text editor and the codeview is working fine when new entries are made into the database.

An entry looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "c7PMjuqnAfNbpdC2T",
    "title" : "Testing fontsize",
    "description" : "<p><span style=\"font-size: 12px;\">asdadsasd</span></p><p><span style=\"font-size: 18px;\" class=\"\">asdasda</span></p><p><span style=\"font-size: 24px;\" class=\"\">asdasdsad</span></p><p><br></p>",
    "cleanDescription" : "asdadsasdasdasdaasdasdsad",
    "category" : "strategy",
    "keywords" : [ 
        "rss", 
        "fml"
    ],
    "type" : "news",
    "createdAt" : "Mon, 01 Aug 2016 09:00:12 +0200",
    "publishedAt" : "Mon, 01 Aug 2016 09:00:12 +0200",
    "publishedRawFormat" : ISODate("2016-08-01T19:00:12.080Z"),
    "coverImageId" : "Wt5cB8cuHu7BWSh7h",
    "attachmentId" : "vJYGX8rpXaKighgL2"
}
```

This is how the codeview looks like:
[image: summernote bad codeview]

My JS file:

```
Template.adminNewsEventsEdit.helpers({
  //...
  afterLoad: function(){ //Fire the code when the page is full loaded.
    Meteor.setTimeout(function(){ //Latency compensation 0.8sec
    $('#description').summernote({
        height: 200,
        toolbar: [
       // [groupName, [list of button]]
        ['style', ['style']],
        ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        //['fontname', ['fontname']],
        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['height', ['height']],
        ['table', ['table']],
        ['insert', ['link', 'hr']], // 'picture', is tooked out
        ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
        ['help', ['help']]
        ]
    });
//...
```

The html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{title}}" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div name="description" id="description">
                            {{{description}}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
...
```

The whole code can be found here:
https://github.com/OpenStratNet/OSN/tree/master/client/templates/admin

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you pass `prettifyHtml: false` in your summernote options? E.g. `$('#description').summernote({ prettifyHtml: false, ... });`

Comment: tested it, didn't have any effect :(